# How to store address in database?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have laravel application where user can select address

```
area
region
city
locality
street
```

Every field is simple integer (foreign key to table which contains all addresses with their parent-child relationship). For example, area `test` has 8 `regions` and 2 `cities`.

I want to store this info in mysql database, but there are some problems.

There is a lot of code which works fine and process all updates to all models (stores info about what was changed with diffs of updates).

If I store these fields if 5 different columns, then I have to add some code in different parts of application to process it (select, update, show), because this code relies upon field type (text, integer, select, etc., there is separate config which describes these columns).

I want to store it in json column like this

```
{"area": 10, "city": 335}
```

Then I can easily add new `columns`, but what about speed of this solution, because these fields will be used in filter and there will be at least 50k rows in table.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Laravel **$casts** parameter on your model [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting):

```
protected $casts = [
    'address' => 'array',
];

$record = SomeModel::find(1);

// $address is an array...
$address = $record->options;

// address is automatically serialized back to JSON...
$user->address = ["area" => 10, "city" => 335];
```

Comment: Laravel internally manages *cast* fields and fetches JSON from table as PHP Array and Stores PHP Array as Json but in migration file make sure that field type is text.

Answer (score -1):

If you have filters over your address then its HIGHLY recommended to make them in separate columns, even if they require modification in various places in your application.

And by filter i mean filtering the result while making the query like you want to get rows where `area` is 10 and so on.

Although if you are at liberty of filtering data after retrieval from database then you can very well use datatype `text` to store json string in database and after retrieving it from database, make `json_decode` and filter it out.

This last case is actually beneficial when you are taking out result in pagination **without** showing total number of found results.

In that case you can query your database for every 10 rows( or whatever number of results you wanna show per page), filter them after retrieval and then fetch more if it doesnt meet the limit. Keep track of offset for further queries.